Merge tiff files from python pdf2image
I'm using pdf2image in Python to export PDF to various image format including "multiframe" TIFFs with multiple pages.
This code works pretty well for TIFF export:
images = convert_from_path(p_filePath, dpi = DPI, poppler_path = POPPLER_PATH)
images[0].save(os.path.join(p_targetPath, outputFilename), self.realType, save_all=True, 
                        append_images=images[1:], compression='tiff_adobe_deflate')

I want to merge new images into this TIFF file, sourced from another PDF, when I detect that one with the same name already exists.
My approach is to:

use convert_from_path as usual to get a pillow image list
extend my image list with images that are already in the tiff
save to TIFF

I tried to implement this in two different ways - by re-building a list using ImageSequence.Iterator like so:
# Merge tiff if already exists
def mergeTiff(self, p_imageList, p_destDir, p_outputFilename):
    imageList = []
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(p_destDir, p_outputFilename)):
        for page in ImageSequence.Iterator(Image.open(os.path.join(p_destDir, p_outputFilename))):
            imageList.append(page)
    imageList.extend(p_imageList)
    return imageList

# then, later:

images = self.mergeTiff(images, p_targetPath, outputFilename)
images[0].save(os.path.join(p_targetPath, outputFilename), self.realType, save_all=True, 
                        append_images=images[1:], compression='tiff_adobe_deflate')

As well as by just opening the already existing TIFF and saving from there with the other image list, like so:
image = Image.open(os.path.join(p_destDir, p_outputFilename))
images = convert_from_path(p_filePath, dpi = DPI, poppler_path = POPPLER_PATH)
image.save(os.path.join(p_targetPath, outputFilename), self.realType, save_all=True, 
                        append_images=images, compression='tiff_adobe_deflate')

But either way, this raises an exception like so:
c:\Users\472573\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py:868: UserWarning: Corrupt EXIF data.  Expecting to read 2 bytes but only got 0. 
  warnings.warn(str(msg))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\472573\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 2138, in _save_all
    ims.seek(idx)
  File "c:\Users\472573\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1123, in seek
    self._seek(frame)
  File "c:\Users\472573\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1169, in _seek
    self._setup()
  File "c:\Users\472573\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1345, in _setup
    xsize = int(self.tag_v2.get(IMAGEWIDTH))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\472573\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\runpy.py", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\472573\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\runpy.py", line 88, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\472573\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.4.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\472573\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.4.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main    run()
  File "c:\Users\472573\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.4.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\Users\472573\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.4.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\472573\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.4.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "c:\Users\472573\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.4.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\472573\Documents\Workspace\python\pdf2image\pdf2imageCHU.py", line 320, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\472573\Documents\Workspace\python\pdf2image\pdf2imageCHU.py", line 304, in main
    pdf2imageObj.processFolder(args.path)
  File "C:\Users\472573\Documents\Workspace\python\pdf2image\pdf2imageCHU.py", line 157, in processFolder
    self.processFile(file.path)
  File "C:\Users\472573\Documents\Workspace\python\pdf2image\pdf2imageCHU.py", line 182, in processFile
    if self.convertToImage(file.name, p_filePath, destDir):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\472573\Documents\Workspace\python\pdf2image\pdf2imageCHU.py", line 122, in convertToImage
    images[0].save(os.path.join(p_targetPath, outputFilename), self.realType, save_all=True,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\472573\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2438, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "c:\Users\472573\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 2143, in _save_all
    im.seek(cur_idx)
  File "c:\Users\472573\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1123, in seek
    self._seek(frame)
  File "c:\Users\472573\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1169, in _seek
    self._setup()
  File "c:\Users\472573\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1345, in _setup
    xsize = int(self.tag_v2.get(IMAGEWIDTH))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'

I thought the first export to TIFF might be corrupted (missing EXIF information), but it seems okay. Counting pages with seek works fine:
def count_pages(img):
    i = 0                                                                           
    while True:
        try:   
            img.seek(i)
        except EOFError:
            break       
        i += 1          
    return i

And also merging two tiffs generated the exact same way using tifftools works fine as well.
So the issue doesn't seem to be with how I create the TIFF file in the first place.
Obviously, the list I'm building contains two different types :
PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile and the native PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile output type from convert_from_path.
What exactly is going wrong, and how do I fix it? Is img.seek failing to get information from the PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFiles?
I could obviously save two files and use tifftools to merge them into one in a kind of postprocessing step. But how can I merge the files directly in the Python code, without generating temp files?

Regarding the first attempt, I can't understand how it is expected to work. It appears that you create a list called imageList in the first block, and then use the second to create the file - but the second block does not mention imageList anywhere. Aside from that, please show a complete error message by copying and pasting, starting from Traceback (most recent call last): all the way to the end. Please also keep in mind that this is not a discussion forum; try to get straight to the point and ask a question directly.

Thx. Please check edit. I detailed first attempt and copied full error.
I don't see where I take it as a discussion forum. I'm just trying to give enough context to avoid stupid questions

Re discussion, please carefully review my edit to understand good practice for writing questions. This question can probably be cut down quite a bit more once the cause of the problem is understood, but I'll leave that to people who are actually familiar with the specific tools you are using.

Thx Karl! Better indeed. And will do if ever a reply points out to the issue
